# What is the difference between the downloading php response by chunks and completely once using WinInet?

Tags: c++, winapi, wininet

I'm sending a post request, and have to read an answer. The size of answer equals 10 000 bytes, for example. Why should I run a loop and get it by parts(1024 bytes per iteration, for example) instead of calling `InternetReadFile(hConnection,buffer,actually_the_size_of_answer,&read)`?

Comment: If you always have a fixed size response then just allocate the buffer and call `InternetReadFile`  If however the response (now or in the future) could be of an unknown size then you have to loop anyway.  So the always loop code-pattern is the more common, can be put into a function and called from many places returning the complete response and size read.

Comment: @RichardCritten, but even if I don't know the size, I can call `InternetReadFile` passing some big value as the third parameter, and then, after call, explore the size via `&read` variable, no? And does it *influence* on the speed of reading?

Comment: Sure so long as you "guess" a big enough size - what happens if you guess too small?  Making a reasonable size guess and looping just-in-case is safe code.

Comment: @RichardCritten, in my cases it impossible, but I understood You. And how about speed? Does it depends on reading by chunks, or completly?

Comment: Your computer is fast, the Internet is slow (Ethernet is slow compared to CPU/memory speeds). IO speed is not an issue.

Comment: @RichardCritten, understood, thank You

Comment: You can’t just “pass some big value” since you have to have _already_ allocated a `buffer` of the size you give.

Comment: @DavisHerring Come on, I meant that the buffer's size is the same as "some big value"

Comment: @ArturKlochko: Of course.  But do you _want_ to allocate "some big amount" of memory?

Comment: How is PHP related? If it isn't, remove it. Besides, if you prefer doing something one way over another, you need to explain, why doing it that way is indeed superior. As written, it just reads like opinion.

Comment: @DavisHerring, yes I know that it is not a good way, but I prefer it

Comment: @IInspectable `echo` `readfile`, and another ways, with which help site could response are php, no?

Comment: That was pretty incomprehensible, but I assume that you believe that your server dynamically builds web pages using one of a bazillion different programming languages makes a difference. It doesn't.

Comment: @IInspectable, I don't know how does serveer builds web pages, I don't think about it. I don't good at web (as in c++ -_-), I'm just using `readfile` to throw files to client, and `echo` to common responses